# Как получить отдельные переменные содержащие каждый символ строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, переменные

Как получить отдельные переменные содержащие каждый символ строки?
Цель:

```
text = "Привет"
a1 = Первая буква слова(переменной text)
```

И так далее...

Comment: text и так можно адресовать списком.

Comment: @MaxU копировать в список не нужно: text уже является последовательностью. Правда это не последовательность букв в общем случае (см. дубликат по ссылке)

Comment: @AndyShevchenko & jfs согласен, это излишне. Удалил свой комментарий